# Graphana "State Timeline" from Prometheus Enum type

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have an enumerated value in Prometheus with three choices (a, b, c) that I want to plot in Grafana as a State Timeline.

```
# HELP my_enum My Enumerated Type
# TYPE my_enum gauge
my_enum{my_enum="a"} 1.0
my_enum{my_enum="b"} 0.0
my_enum{my_enum="c"} 0.0
```

One of the choices (a, b, c) is set to 1.0 at a time, the rest are set to 0.  I can plot the data as a time series with three separate traces, although I would like to combine them into a single state timeline.

Is there a Grafana transformation that I need to apply?

Answer (score 0):

There is now such transformation in Grafana, AFAIK.

But you could use trick, that I used to display status of windows services in State Timeline. Make your query as

```
my_enum{my_enum="a"} + 2*my_enum{my_enum="b"} + 3*my_enum{my_enum="c"}
```

and configure `Value mappings` as

```
1 -> a (color of a)
2 -> b (color of b)
3 -> c (color of c)
```